# Parsing a http response that is in bytes format

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

`requests.get()` receives a `response` which is of the type bytes. It looks like:

```
b'{"Close":8506.25,"DownTicks":164,"DownVolume":207,"High":8508.25,"Low":8495.00,"Open":8496.75,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\\/Date(1583530800000)\\/","TotalTicks":371,"TotalVolume":469,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":207,"UpVolume":262,"OpenInterest":0}\r\n{"Close":8503.00,"DownTicks":152,"DownVolume":203,"High":8509.50,"Low":8502.00,"Open":8506.00,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\\/Date(1583531100000)\\/","TotalTicks":282,"TotalVolume":345,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":130,"UpVolume":142,"OpenInterest":0}\r\n{"Close":8494.00,"DownTicks":160,"DownVolume":206,"High":8505.75,"Low":8492.75,"Open":8503.25,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\\/Date(1583531400000)\\/","TotalTicks":275,"TotalVolume":346,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":115,"UpVolume":140,"OpenInterest":0}\r\n{"Close":8499.00,"DownTicks":136,"DownVolume":192,"High":8500.25,"Low":8492.25,"Open":8493.75,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\\/Date(1583531700000)\\/","TotalTicks":299,"TotalVolume":402,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":163,"UpVolume":210,"OpenInterest":0}\r\n{"Close":8501.75,"DownTicks":176,"DownVolume":314,"High":8508.25,"Low":8495.75,"Open":8498.50,"Status":536870941,"TimeStamp":"\\/Date(1583532000000)\\/","TotalTicks":340,"TotalVolume":510,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":164,"UpVolume":196,"OpenInterest":0}\r\nEND'
```

Please note that while the actual string is much longer, it is always a long string of shorter strings separated by `'\r\n'`, ignoring the final word "END". You can see how similarly-structured these short strings are:

```
for i in response.text.split('\r\n')[:-1]: print(i, '\n\n')

{"Close":8506.25,"DownTicks":164,"DownVolume":207,"High":8508.25,"Low":8495.00,"Open":8496.75,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\/Date(1583530800000)\/","TotalTicks":371,"TotalVolume":469,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":207,"UpVolume":262,"OpenInterest":0} 


{"Close":8503.00,"DownTicks":152,"DownVolume":203,"High":8509.50,"Low":8502.00,"Open":8506.00,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\/Date(1583531100000)\/","TotalTicks":282,"TotalVolume":345,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":130,"UpVolume":142,"OpenInterest":0} 


{"Close":8494.00,"DownTicks":160,"DownVolume":206,"High":8505.75,"Low":8492.75,"Open":8503.25,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\/Date(1583531400000)\/","TotalTicks":275,"TotalVolume":346,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":115,"UpVolume":140,"OpenInterest":0} 


{"Close":8499.00,"DownTicks":136,"DownVolume":192,"High":8500.25,"Low":8492.25,"Open":8493.75,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\/Date(1583531700000)\/","TotalTicks":299,"TotalVolume":402,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":163,"UpVolume":210,"OpenInterest":0} 


{"Close":8501.75,"DownTicks":176,"DownVolume":314,"High":8508.25,"Low":8495.75,"Open":8498.50,"Status":536870941,"TimeStamp":"\/Date(1583532000000)\/","TotalTicks":340,"TotalVolume":510,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":164,"UpVolume":196,"OpenInterest":0}
```

***Goal*** parsing a few of the fields and saving them in a dataframe with the field "Timestamp" as the dataframe's index.

What I have done:

```
response_text = response.text

import ast

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [ 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v'])

for i in response_text.split('\r\n')[:-1]:
    i_dict = ast.literal_eval(i)
    epoch_in_milliseconds = int(i_dict['TimeStamp'].split('(')[1].split(')')[0])

    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(epoch_in_milliseconds)/1000.)
    o = i_dict['Open']
    h = i_dict['High']
    l = i_dict['Low']
    c = i_dict['Close']
    v = i_dict['TotalVolume']
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'o':o, 'h':h, 'l':l, 'c':c, 'v':v}, index = [time_stamp])

    df = df.append(temp_df)
```

which gets me:

```
In [546]df
Out[546]: 
                             o          h          l          c    v
2020-03-06 16:40:00 8496.75000 8508.25000 8495.00000 8506.25000  469
2020-03-06 16:45:00 8506.00000 8509.50000 8502.00000 8503.00000  345
2020-03-06 16:50:00 8503.25000 8505.75000 8492.75000 8494.00000  346
2020-03-06 16:55:00 8493.75000 8500.25000 8492.25000 8499.00000  402
2020-03-06 17:00:00 8498.50000 8508.25000 8495.75000 8501.75000  510
```

which is exactly what I need.

***Issue*** this method feels clumsy to me, like a patch-work, and prone to breaking due to possible slight differences in the response text.

Is there any more robust and faster way of extracting this information from the original bytes? (When the server response is in JSON format, I have none of this headache)

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat cleaner, I believe:

```
ts = """
b'{"Close":8506.25,"DownTicks":164,"DownVolume":207,"High":8508.25,"Low":8495.00,"Open":8496.75,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\\/Date(1583530800000)\\/","TotalTicks":371,"TotalVolume":469,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":207,"UpVolume":262,"OpenInterest":0}\r\n{"Close":8503.00,"DownTicks":152,"DownVolume":203,"High":8509.50,"Low":8502.00,"Open":8506.00,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\\/Date(1583531100000)\\/","TotalTicks":282,"TotalVolume":345,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":130,"UpVolume":142,"OpenInterest":0}\r\n{"Close":8494.00,"DownTicks":160,"DownVolume":206,"High":8505.75,"Low":8492.75,"Open":8503.25,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\\/Date(1583531400000)\\/","TotalTicks":275,"TotalVolume":346,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":115,"UpVolume":140,"OpenInterest":0}\r\n{"Close":8499.00,"DownTicks":136,"DownVolume":192,"High":8500.25,"Low":8492.25,"Open":8493.75,"Status":13,"TimeStamp":"\\/Date(1583531700000)\\/","TotalTicks":299,"TotalVolume":402,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":163,"UpVolume":210,"OpenInterest":0}\r\n{"Close":8501.75,"DownTicks":176,"DownVolume":314,"High":8508.25,"Low":8495.75,"Open":8498.50,"Status":536870941,"TimeStamp":"\\/Date(1583532000000)\\/","TotalTicks":340,"TotalVolume":510,"UnchangedTicks":0,"UnchangedVolume":0,"UpTicks":164,"UpVolume":196,"OpenInterest":0}\r\nEND'
"""
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import json

data = []
tss = ts.replace("b'","").replace("\r\nEND'","")
tss2 = tss.strip().split("\r\n")
for t in tss2:
    item = json.loads(t)
    epo = int(item['TimeStamp'].split('(')[1].split(')')[0])    
    eims = datetime.fromtimestamp(epo/1000)    
    item.update(TimeStamp=eims)
    data.append(item)
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
    Close   DownTicks   DownVolume  High    Low     Open    Status  TimeStamp   TotalTicks  TotalVolume     UnchangedTicks  UnchangedVolume     UpTicks     UpVolume    OpenInterest
0   8506.25     164     207     8508.25     8495.00     8496.75     13  2020-03-06 16:40:00     371     469     0   0   207     262     0
1   8503.00     152     203     8509.50     8502.00     8506.00     13  2020-03-06 16:45:00     282     345     0   0   130     142     0
```

etc. You can drop unwanted columns, change column names and so on.

Answer (score 0):

That's *almost* JSON format. Or more precisely, it's a series of lines, each of which contains a JSON-formatted object. (Except for the last one.) So that suggests that the optimal solution in some way uses the `json` module.

`json.load` doesn't handle files consisting of a series of lines, nor does it directly handle individual strings (much less `bytes`). However, you're not limited to `json.load`. You can construct a [`JSONDecoder` object](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html?highlight=json%20decoder#encoders-and-decoders), which does include methods to parse from strings (but not from `bytes`), and you can use the `decode` method of the `bytes` object to construct a string from the input. (You need to know the encoding to do that, but I strongly suspect that in this case all the characters are ascii, so either `'ascii'` or the default UTF-8 encoding will work.)

Unless your input is gigabytes, you can just use the strategy in your question: split the input into lines, discard the `END` line, and pass the rest into a `JSONDecoder`:

```
import json
decoder = JSONDecoder()
# Using splitlines seemed more robust than counting on a specific line-end
for line in response_text.decode().splitlines()
    # Alternative: use a try/catch around the call to decoder.decode
    if line == 'END': break
    line_dict = decoder.decode(line)
    # Handle the Timestamp member and create the dataframe item
```